# adjusting steps on y-axis on Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I need to adjust the steps on the y-axis on Gnuplot, however, I don't succeed to do this,

NOTE that I don't want to use "logscale", so I need to just have the numbers appropriate to the x-axis values and I don't want too many steps on the y-axis to show up on the y-axis, how can I do this?

here is the result I want to achieve,

The image result I wish:

[image]

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you consulted the manual? Have you checked `help ytics`?

Comment: Yes, I found it in the manual related to xtics, 
```
set ytics <start>, <incr>, <end>
```

Comment: Great! Any question to that or clarification needed?

Comment: it perfectly worked, Gnuplot is amazing, That setting was needed to don't crowed the figure for the publication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of not letting this (basic) question appear unanswered:

Please check the manual (before asking on SO ;-). You can also find it if you type `help xtics`.

> ```
> Syntax: 
>
>       set xtics {axis | border} {{no}mirror}
>                 {in | out} {scale {default | <major> {,<minor>}}}
>                 {{no}rotate {by <ang>}} {offset <offset> | nooffset}
>                 {left | right | center | autojustify}
>                 {add}
>                 {  autofreq
>                  | <incr>
>                  | <start>, <incr> {,<end>}
>                  | ({"<label>"} <pos> {<level>} {,{"<label>"}...) }
>                 {format "formatstring"} {font "name{,<size>}"} {{no}enhanced}
>                 { numeric | timedate | geographic }
>                 {{no}logscale}
>                 { rangelimited }
>                 { textcolor <colorspec> }
> ```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ytics`?

Comment: @Neil if you type `help ytics` you will be redirected to `xtics`. There is no extra help entry for `ytics` because it's the same syntax.

Comment: @theozh would you please advise me about a new problem that I faced. How can I have manually set the ytics? not the labels, I want to define an irregular pattern for ytics, for instance, 1,3,9,12,15,18,...,90.  this can not be done with the ``` set ytics <start>, <incr>, <end>```  can I define any formula in <incr> section?

Comment: @Elephant88 Please have a closer look at the syntax and furthermore check `help xtics list`.  For example: `set xtics {add} ("label1" <pos1> <level1>, "label2" <pos2> <level2>, ...)`